# Brightcove: How to display a videos view count using javascript?

Tags: javascript, brightcove

I'm trying to display a videos view count outside Brightcoves player.

BC Support provided this link: http://developer.brightcove.com/en/articles/displaying-number-video-views-your-player, but it doesn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: did you have any luck with this?

Comment: unfortunately, the project fell through, so I never had a chance to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to create the view as part of the player, you really only need to pay attention to the API call:

```
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.token = _mediaKey;
variables.command = 'find_video_by_id';
variables.video_id = id;
variables.video_fields = 'playsTotal';
```

Check here for examples of using the [JavaScript API](http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/javascript-media-api-examples)